# Can two different Double objects share same memory location in Java?

Tags: java, double, heap-memory

I have some classes like following in my code (not the exact classes but similar structure).

```
class Shop {
  Item item;
  Service service;
}

class Item {
  ...
  Amount amt;
  ...
} 

class Service {
  ...
  Amount amt;
  ...
} 

class Amount {
  Double value;
  String currencyCode;
}
```

I am running into very weird situation where changing `value` field of `Amount` in `item` object is changing `value` field of `Amount` in `service` object. 
Is Java somehow sharing the same memory for these two objects? If yes, what's the solution to avoid this?

Comment: It means you're using the same instance of `Amount`

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 different double objects? No.

But 2 different objects (a Service object, and an Item object) certainly can both have a variable whose value references (if you're from C, it's a pointer, we just call them 'references' in java) the same Amount instance.

Consider all variables (except primitives) treasure maps, and all objects treasure.

If I bury some treasure on the beach, and draw a map to my treasure, that's one thing. If I then scribble out a *copy* of my map, and give you this copy, then it doesn't matter what you do to your map's copy. Throw it in a shredder for all I care; I won't notice (in java: if the Item does 'amt = null', that won't affect the Service object's amt at all).

But, if you take your copy of the treasure map, follow it, dig up the treasure you find there and smash it to bits... I'm gonna notice.

2 treasure maps, but only one treasure.

2 fixes available:

1. Make defensive copies of mutable objects before you hand them off to other code, or generally preferred:
2. Make your objects immutable, An Amount object's constructor should set its value and currencyCode, and then it should not allow these to ever change; the `value` and `currencyCode` variables should be declared final.

immutable objects are like indestructible treasure. Then it doesn't matter anymore that everybody knows where it is buried, they can only look at it, can't change it anymore.

NB: Putting currency values in doubles is a very very silly idea; not every number in existence can be accurately represented as a double. You should store cents instead (so, `long cents;` or perhaps you can make do with `int cents;`. Where 'cent' is the atomic tiniest amount that the currencyCode you're representing allows for transfer at e.g. banks and the like. So, for USD that'd be a cent, same for euros, for japanese yen it's 1 yen. For bitcoin it'd be 1 satoshi (0.00000001 BTC) - all currencies have some effectively indivisible amount. Represent those. As a long. Tada! Now the rounding behaviour is easy to understand, unlike with doubles.

Comment: Thank, upon looking more into the code I found out that both objects were referencing the same object. As I said in the question, actual code is more complicated than shown above, so really had to debug it properly to find out the same reference.

Comment: I know using Double is not correct to represent the money, but it's a legacy code which is being used company wide so have to use it like that for now.

Comment: @ScaryWombat BigDecimal is highly complex: [1] try to divide 1 dollar by 3 people in BigDecimal. You get an exception. This is in some ways good, but it does show that BigDecimal is no silver bullet. [2] is 0.1 equal to 0.10? both are representable! [3] what about 2 bd's representing the same number, but with a different scale? Equal?  BigDecimal is a bazooka, and a hard one to use at that. longs to represent the atomic unit works far better.

Comment: @ScaryWombat write this java and execute it: `BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.0));`

Comment: @ScaryWombat it would produce 33. It's equally problematic. The real answer is: it depends on what 'divide by' means in this context. If it's a fee that 3 people are supposed to pay to the bank and you are the bank, the likely desired answer is 'round up' (each pays 34 cents). If it's a benefit that is to be spread evenly, it's 'round down': Each gets 33. Alternate answer: Randomly pick a person. That person does 34 cents, the other 2 do 33. And so on. The clue is: You must think in atomic units _ANYWAY_, so BIgDecimal buys you absolutely nothing of use whatsoever.

Comment: @ScaryWombat just so we're clear, I'm pretty sure the burden of proof is the shoulders of BIgDecimal, given that it complicates matters so much. It needs to show how it can do currencies fundamentally better than longs and ints can; there is a high cost associated (lots of code, the ability to have sub-atomic amounts which need to be dealt with at some point, doesn't integrate well with DBs, JSON, and many other forms of communication, doesn't map to bank APIs, bad performance). Are the benefits sufficient to warrant that cost? That'd be for those advocating 'store currency in BD!' to show.

Comment: I stick by my wording. I have shown how it's considerably more practical than BigDecimal and considerably more correct than double. How does that not warrant a 'you should'?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I gave you falsifiable, objective arguments. You respond with an appeal to the masses instead of delving into the vagaries of practical problems faced when dealing with currencies. Development is hard enough; I strongly prefer to stick with objective arguments and not bring 'this SO answer from 9 years ago has 150 points!' appeals into it.